# Compute capacitance of planar interdigital electrodes

Tags: capacitance, inductance, sensor

My apologies if this is not the right place to post a question like this.

I am looking to do post-grad research study next year in the sensory field for sensing gases like hydrogen, nitrogen or ammonia (not decided yet). So trying to understand what is out there and how best to approach the task of measuring capacitance (never done this before) using a microprocessor. I have been evaluating different ways of measuring capacitance from these planar electrode (required to use this particular sensor, photo below) using a microcontroller such as a Arduino/Nucleo board as this needs to be portable/field deployable. I have been told these planar electrodes have a capacitance of approximately 9pF in air, computed using B&K Precision LCR meter.
[image]

I have come across many papers where they calculate the impedance of the sensor using EIS (Electrochemical Impedance Spectroscopy) method but I am looking to measure capacitance instead. Most of these papers are Engineering related so I will stick to physics questions instead.

I was looking at LC tank/resonant circuit to measure the resonant frequency and then connect the planar electrodes in parallel to the circuit and measure the frequency again. The problem with this approach is that the resonant frequency is fixed whereas I need to be able to sweep frequencies from 100 Hz to 1 MHz to evaluate the capacitance values from the planar electrode at different frequencies. Generating the sinusoidal signals for the above frequencies will be carried out by Analog Devices AD9951. But I have no clue how to go about measuring the capacitance of these electrodes without an oscilloscope and equations can be used. Any suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: Am I right in thinking you're trying to measure the capacitance at multiple frequencies, and at high precision?
In a research environment, you should just purchase the [relevant equipment](https://www.digikey.com.au/en/products/detail/b&k-precision/891/5427361)

Comment: @catalogue_number, we have the exact same LCR meter at uni but my project has a point-of-care aspect to it which is why I can't use lab equipment.

Answer (score 1):

If the objective is just to test the sensor on its own, it would be *much* easier to purchase a programmable bench LCR meter similar to [this one](https://au.element14.com/b-k-precision/bk895/precision-lcr-meter-bench-1mhz/dp/2717336). This has the specs you require, but if you want to develop your own device to measure the capacitance you essentially need to build your own LC meter, which is *not a trivial task*. The analog measurement modules of precision test equipment like this are the result of decades of R&D, and making something even close to a commercial device will take substantial time and money. The expense and difficulty comes from the need to measure capacitance at an *arbitrary* frequency - if you only needed to know the capacitance at, say, 10kHz, it would be much easier.

That being said, I can suggest a path for your research if you do wnat to produce a self contained sensor:

1. Characterise the frequency response of a particular sensor geometry/material using an LCR meter, and watch for which frequencies are most sensitive to the chemicals you're interested in.
2. Design an LC meter that is accurate at measuring the capacitance at these "characteristic frequencies".
3. Come up with a heuristic to convert these capacitances into concentrations.

Comment: that is a very good suggestion. thank you. Like you mentioned, it would be much easier if the frequency was known right? What if I use AD9951 to generate a frequency and compute the capacitance. Would you be able to supply the formulae to calculate the capacitance from frequency. The formulas I came across all have an inductance component to it.

Comment: The LC formula (for the resonant frequency of a capacitor-inductor system)  will not be much use to you on its own, the question of measuring it electronically is arguably better suited to electronics stack exchange.